# Preventing map from dragging while mouse is within InfoBox (but also allowing text highlighting)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm using `react-google-maps`, and I have an InfoBox that opens on marker click, with some text, input fields within it.

I have a dilemma and am quite stuck. I would like to allow the user to highlight text in the input fields (within the InfoBox).

Currently, highlighting/dragging the mouse within an InfoBox will pan the underlying map.

I understand that google maps has a `gestureHandling` option that if set to `'none'`, will prevent dragging. This is not possible for me since settting gestureHandling to 'none' while mouse is inside InfoBox will also prevent clicking and selection of input fields.

I have tried `<GoogleMap onDrag />`, but drag events do not expose an 'event' for me to somehow do `event.stopPropagation()`. Hence, is it possible to selectively turn off only map panning, while allowing text highlighting within an InfoBox component?

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l2mymj912m

I do have `enableEventPropagation` set to `true`. Setting it to `false` does enable highlighting, but prevents events like `onClick`.

Comment: I created a [basic example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo93xv080j); it has a marker and an info window (with input elements) that is displayed when the marker is clicked. I have no problems with map panning when I highlight the text within the input elements or drag the mouse anywhere else within the info box. Could you make a similar example app that includes the code which is causing your issue?

Comment: wow thank you for the example! I have forked and modified it to show my issue. post is edited above ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46794606/4481169) and integrated it into your example. This included:

- Setting `enableEventPropagation` to `false` on the `InfoBox` component.
- Adding an id to the button inside the InfoBox (`id="counter-button"`).
- Adding the following prop to the InfoBox component:

  ```
  onDomReady={() => {
    let counterButton = document.getElementById("counter-button");
    counterButton.addEventListener("click", props.onButtonClick);
  }}
  ```

Check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/24w0m8m5wj

Also, here are some links for further reading on the issue:

- [react-google-maps and google event listneres - how to catch events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162513/react-google-maps-and-google-event-listneres-how-to-catch-events)
- https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/84
- https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react/issues/185